# Nested IF(MATCH statements Excel 2003

Tags: excel, formula

Thank you for your help in advance

I have two `If(Match` statements in my Excel worksheet they work separately on their own.

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,'Sales Orders'!A:A,0),"On Pick")

=IF(MATCH(A35,'Stock Reqs'!A:A,0),"On Pick")
```

I have been trying to nest the formulas together but I am struggling quite badly, I tend to get `#NAME` or `#VALUE` errors.

Someone suggested the below, but I think this is not compatible with Excel 2003

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A24,'Sales Orders'!A:A,0),"On Pick",),IF(MATCH(A24,'Stock Reqs'!A:A,0),"On Pick",)),"")
```

Any more guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to explain *how* the first two formulas should work together.

Comment: For Excel 2003, I think you will need to do `If()` with the condition `IsError()`... `IfError()` would be inappropriate for that version.

Comment: Use: `IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,'Sales Orders'!A:A,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A35,'Stock Reqs'!A:A,0))),"On Pick","")`

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner thank you for that, it has worked fine. Are you able to give me a little brief on where I went wrong with this?

Comment: IFERROR does not exist in 2003 Excel.  Like the other comments stated.